# What does it mean "a conditional expectation given a stochastic process"?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, exchangeability

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be a probability space.

Let $X,Y$ be random variables on $\Omega$.

Then, we say $Z\sim X|Y$ iff (i) $\int_{Y^{-1}(A)} X dP = \int_{Y^{-1}(A)} Z dP$ and (ii) $Z$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

Now,  let $S:\mathscr{\mathbb{R}} \times \Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a stochastic process.

What does it mean by $X|S$?

There are numerous papers saying like "... because $X|S \sim S$, $P(X\in A|S)= S(A)...$.

I think this is NOT actually a conditional expectation, but it is just a way to denote De Finneti theorem. Isn't it?

Note that $S$ can be seen as a measurable map $\Omega\rightarrow \prod_{A\in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \mathbb{R}$. **If the definition $X|S$ is consistent with the standard conditional expectation definition**, $X|S$ is a random variable taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, same as $X$. However, since $X|S\sim S$, $X|S$ must take values in  $\prod_{A\in \mathscr{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \mathbb{R}$. Do you see inconsistency here?

This makes me confusing, so I am curious what's the definition of $X|S$.

What does $X|S$ mean?

** EDIT **

Here's the usage of this in "Theory of statistics - Mark J. Schervish"

[image]

As you can see here, the author says "$X_n$'s are independent and identically distributed as $P$ conditional on $\mathbb{P}=P$."

This means that $X|\mathbb{P}\sim \mathbb{P}$, which I do not get how to formally define it.

And

[image]

**Last EDIT**

[image]

The author says that it is a **fact** that $P(X\in A|\mathbb{P}=P)=P(A)$. So there must be another definition the author is referring to..

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=conditional+expectation+sigma+algebra.

Comment: @whuber I know the general sigma algebra definition of conditional expectation. However, as I wrote in my post, saying "$X|S\sim S$" is inconsistent with that standard definition.

Comment: Can you give us an accessible reference to investigate the context of such usage?

Comment: @whuber I added the pictures. Please chek! And thank you.

Comment: It's conditional on a given probability measure P. For instance, suppose B is [0,1], and your P is $\mathcal N(0, 1)$, then $Pr(X_1\in [0,1])=\frac 1 {2\pi}\int_0^1 e^{-x^2/2}dx$

Comment: @Aksakal So is the notation "$X|S \sim S$" has nothing to do with the "formal definition of conditional expectation"? That is, $P(X\in A|S=P)=P(A)$ is the **definition** of $X|S\sim S$?

Comment: @Aksakal Please see the last line in my edited post. So what exactly is the definition of $X|S\sim S$?

Comment: Even more, if $X|S$ **does not** mean the standard conditional distribution, we cannot even talk about $X|S$ in general because we do not know if this object exists. I am guessing it is just a notation made up for De Finneti theorem.. but I am not sure if I am understanding it correctly..

Comment: not sure what you mean by formal definition. if you understand $X|P$ then you understand $X|S$. discrete stochastic process is just a big joint distribution $P(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_t)$ etc

Comment: No offence, but I think there's tautology going on here. So, what exactly is **the definition** of $X|S$? Not examples. According to the author of the textbook I uploaded, the normal distribution example is a "property" of $X|S$, not the definition of $X|S$. Moreover, as I noted in my post, when we view $S$ as a measurable function, the notation $X|S$ here is inconsistent with the standard conditional distribution notation $X|Y$ where $X,Y$ are random variables. So, there must be a wise way to view $S$ so that the notation $X|S$ is consistent with the standard conditional distribution [...]

Comment: [...] notation, **or** there is a completely another way of defining $X|S$. Do you see my point here?

Comment: Pollard's *A User's Guide to Measure Theoretic Probability* has a good coverage of disintegrations and regular conditional distributions (these are more flexible than Kolmogorov-style conditional expectations, but require some topological conditions for their existence)

Answer (score 1):

Now, I get it.

Let $Prob(\mathbb{R})$ be the collection of Borel probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathfrak{M}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of sets $\{\mu\in Prob(\mathbb{R}):\mu(A) < t\}$

Define $\bar{S}(w)(A):=S(w,A)$. Then $\bar{S}:(\Omega,\mathscr{F}) \rightarrow (Prob(\mathbb{R}),\mathfrak{M})$ is a **measurable** function.

Let $\mu_{X|\bar{S}}$ be a regular conditional distribution of $X$ given $\bar{S}$. (I am not sure if this regular version exists in this case. It must exist if $\mathfrak{M}$ is a sub $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of the topology of weak convergence on $Prob(\mathbb{R})$. I think this is true by Portmanteau theorem and the property that every Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ is inner regular, but I have to check the details...)

Now, we write $X|S\sim S$ to mean $\mu_{X|\bar{S}}(\cdot,\lambda) = \lambda$ for almost every $\lambda\in Prob(\mathbb{R})$ with respect to $\bar{S}_*P$ (the push-forward measure).